# IPv6 and/or 'dnsmasq' for DNS | DHCP also

Tags: networking, router, dns, ipv6, dnsmasq

##### Preface

I'm far from being a network manager, and not really know much about IPv6 (yet), but slowly I have to.

I have an RPi4 based server in my home, basically for Home Assistant smart-home automation *(through Docker)*, but as it could nicely handle some additional practical things, I use it as my local DNS relay and my DHCP server with 'dnsmasq'. The base of it is the official Ubuntu - Server 22.10.

I'm in Hungary through Vodafone's wired network, from outside to inside, with their modem, on it my own D-Link DIR-880L router to manage my network with my device instead of their, and on it all my network devices *(wired, or wireless)*.

I need an internal DNS server to handle my internal devices through local domain, and because 'dnsmasq' can nicely handle the DNS and DHCP functions I loved it to use instead of  my router's DHCP config.

I had a working DDNS solution with a proper IPv4 port forward on my router with the bridge mode of the Vodafone modem, so I reached my Home Assistant from remotely, and could link my Home Assistant to Google Home to handle their devices voice controlled.

Everything went fine on IPv4 network until 2 month ago I got a software upgrade on the Vodafone modem, with an 'additional' IPv6 'address'. For first sight it was a bit of shock as I simply did not know anything about IPv6 so I had to acclimate into it, had to know how to use it *(as the new Vodafone modem software does not offer IPv4 NAT, so basically on IPv4 I can never remote manage my internal devices, therefore I had to switch to IPv6 for these requirements)*, but after some weeks it seems that it can/I could serve my needs but there are some problems, what I simply can not understand.

From network aspect currently I get an IPv4 address for my modem, without NAT capability, so here the end of the branch, but of course I get a IPv6/64 subnet which is basically perfect for me with a proper firewall config.

IPv4: My router is on the 192.168.0.0 subnet, managed by the modem's DHCP. My real internal 'lan' is on the 192.168.1.0 subnet managed by the dnsmasq's DHCP4 with my router in router mode as the gateway. It's basically working just can not remote manage without the mentioned NAT function.

IPv6: My router is on the modem's managed stateless DHCP + SLAAC (what can not be disabled), on its IPv6 subnet based on the given prefix. The router is configured with 'Stateless DHCP + SLAAC' and with 'IPv6 Address Assignment' and 'DHCP-PD in LAN' functions enabled. Because of the mentioned lines all my internal device get/generate an auto IPv6 addresses (through SLAAC), but of course those are not managed by me and not fully static, as the there is no statefull DHCP above them. So here steps in the 'dnsmasq' on the RPi, with it's statefull DHCP6 config.

At this point all my devices get 1-1 SLAAC and a statefull DHCP managed IPv6 addresses with working results. It is important that this 'double shot' is very practical, as Android currently does not support statefull DHCP addresses, so with the paralel config all my Android devices also are on IPv6 network *(with the stateless config)*, while all the other devices are on real static addresses managed by the 'dnsmasq's DHCP6.

##### Problems

###### 1.

After fresh device connection onto the network I get immediately the DNS-es from the 'dnsmasq', but randomly some minutes or hours later they automatically changed to the Vodafone ones, therefore from that point I can not reach my internal devices called with their local domain names. I think this is because the available 'stateless DHCP' function of the modem, but sadly I can not disable it. But from an other aspect - as I wrote - because the Android devices I simply need the SLAAC 'sideway' near the 'dnsmasq' offered satefull DHCP6 also. But - I think - basically here the problem is not the paralel SLAAC just the 'stateless DHCP' function of the modem which 'broadcast' it's DNS-es and which from time-to-time override my 'dnsmasq' offered DNS-es.

Do I see properly the situation? **Are there any ideas how to handle it?**

###### 2.

As my IPv6 subnet is lot more static :D than the previous IPv4 address, I changed my previously used DDNS to my own paid domain *(of course I'm not meaning of the local ones)* with the fix-configured AAAA record pointed to my RPi's static IPv6 address *(it's address is real static as itself is the statefull DHCP server)*. I can nicely reach the Home Assistant with the domain above the mentioned AAAA record *(currently using a named but basically default bridged network in Docker)*, but... on Android devices from time-to-time the IPv6 network seems to broken somehaw, where the most interesting part of it that I simply do not know where and how?!

After a fresh Android device connection I can reach my Home Assistant through the mentioned domain *(what is not local)*, so the resolve of the corresponding domain is working, as the IPv6 network also, because the domain has just AAAA record. Some time later from the same Android device I simply can not reach my Home Assistant through he domain, but can reach through its IPv6 address. WTH?! The IPv6 network still works, but loose the domain resolving? Which in this case is not only handled my 'dnsmasq' DNS relay, as the corresponding domain is not local, it is really finely distributed/propagated already. So it is really a black hole for me. **What could happen here?**

After disconnecting the Android device from the network and reconnect again, for some minutes I have proper 'chain' again, but a few times later again I can not reach my Home Assistant just with its IPv6 address, instead of the domain, while all other domain resolving seems fine. Sadly at this point I'm not sure when I use IPv4 or IPv6 processes, so could be that the all other DNS resolutions seems working just because the working IPv4, and just the IPv6 branch is broken, but in this case how can I reach the Home Assistant through its IPv6 address?!.

As I wrote I'm not perfectly acclimated into the IPv6 world, but from one aspect seems everything fine, while from another not so :(.

###### 3.

The whole IPv6 world is fine, my only problem is just as Vodafone in Hungary does not offer IPv6 addresses on its mobile network *(which is used by me also)*, so if all the above would be fine, I could not reach my home and Home Assistant from mobile. But this 'small problem' in theory could be handled with Google Home/Google Assistant, as if that service can handle my Home Assistant, Google Home itself can be reachable on IPv4 also, so it could be a bridge between the 2 'network', but sadly I can not set-up my Home Assistant to be available through Google Home, also from the start of my brand new IPv6 world. Previously *(on IPv4 only)* this was worked perfectly also. But this is really not so raw server/network config question, so I'm not detailing it here as this is a Home Assistant/Google Home problem which is another topic *(and another forum :D, where the funny part of it, that some years ago me was the one who wrote the step by step instruction to how to configure it, to the persons who lost in the official documentation)*.

**Lot of thanks in advance, if anybody can drive me to the right direction(s)...**

*(If it help of course I will drop configs/etc, but for first I thought if I'm writing down the whole structure someone could point me on the most problematic parts of it.)*